# Почему при разных кросс-валидациях в результате получается одинаковый ответ?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, аналитика

выборка поделена в соотношении 80 на 20, а кросс-валидацию использую 5, 10, 20;
в итоге процент несовпадений выдает одинаковое число, по правилам ответы должны быть разными. что не так?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from logitboost import LogitBoostClassifier   
from gentleboost import GentleBoostClassifier
from __future__ import division, print_function
# отключим всякие предупреждения 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Vika\\Downloads\\kvz.csv', ";",decimal =',')
data.head()
kfold = 20
itog_val1 = {} 
itog_val2 = {} 
itog_val3 = {} 
itog_val4 = {} 
itog_val5 = {}
itog_val6 = {} 
itog_val7 = {}
itog_val8 = {}
X = data.drop('Y1', axis=1).values[:, :8] 
y = data['Y1'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 8)
#X_train.shape, X_test.shape 
print ('обучающая выборка X:\n', X_train[:6])
print ('\n')
print ('y_train У:\n', y_train[:10])
print (' \n')
print ('тестовая выборка Х:\n', X_test[:6])
print ('\n')
print ('y_test У\n', y_test[:10])
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100)    
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val1 = scores
print(itog_val1)  
clf2 = LogitBoostClassifier (n_estimators=100) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf2, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val5 = scores
print(itog_val5)
clf4 = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100)    
scores = cross_val_score(clf4, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val3 = scores
print(itog_val3)  
clf3 = GentleBoostClassifier (n_estimators=100) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf3, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val7 = scores
print(itog_val7)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
# clf.predict(X_test)
y_test_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
print ('AdaBoostClassifier: \n  X_test\n', X_test[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('AdaBoostClassifier:  \n y_test\n', y_test[:31])
clf4.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf4.score(X_test, y_test)
# clf.predict(X_test)
y_test_predicted1 = clf4.predict(X_test)
print ('GradientBoostingClassifier:\n X_test\n', X_test[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('GradientBoostingClassifier: \n y_test\n', y_test[:11])
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf2.score(X_test, y_test)
# clf.predict(X_test)
y_test_predicted2 = clf2.predict(X_test)
print ('LogitBoostClassifier:\n X_test\n', X_test[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('LogitBoostClassifier: \n y_test\n', y_test[:11])
clf3.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf3.score(X_test, y_test)
# clf.predict(X_test)
y_test_predicted3 = clf3.predict(X_test)
print ('GentleBoostClassifier:\n X_test\n', X_test[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('GentleBoostClassifier: \n y_test\n', y_test[:11])
res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)), 
                   columns=['Y1','YPAB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
                   res.head(2)
                   (res['Y1']!= res['YPAB']).mean()
                   res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted1, X_test)), 
                   columns=['Y1','YPGB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
                   res.head(2)
                   (res['Y1']!= res['YPGB']).mean()
                   res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted2, X_test)), 
                   columns=['Y1','YPGENB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
                   res.head(2)
                   (res['Y1']!= res['YPGENB']).mean()
                   res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted3, X_test)), 
                   columns=['Y1','YPLB'] + data.columns[1:9].tolist())
                   res.head(2)
                   (res['Y1']!= res['YPLB']).mean()
```

Comment: нашла ошибку в коде, надо было изменить random state